# Feature Request - Down Vote Explanation

Tags: feature-request, comments, down-votes

When an OP asks for a down vote clarification, power users should be able to click a button to add the [following comment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17162/is-asking-employees-to-wear-formal-clothing-on-client-visit-meaningful#comment41809_17162):

> In the absence of a specific comment, you might find it useful to assume that a downvote means the downvoter thought that "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful", since that's what the downvote button offers as a tooltip.

Comment: I generally do this when I see downvoted posts with no explanation.

Comment: You can [script that](http://stackapps.com/q/2116/21539), FYI.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: Umm... That's awesome!!! Thanks, Monica!

Comment: Ok, if that addresses the need I'll put it in an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This user script from StackApps](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/21539) allows you to add pro-forma comments to any post on any site.  It comes with some standard ones, but you can edit the list to either change those or add new ones.  A "welcome to our site" message is a good one to have (with link to the "about" page, optionally).  You can use this script to create a comment like the one in the question.

When using pro-forma comments you should *always* review for that specific context before just clicking "post".  The script gives you an edit buffer, not a posted comment, for just that reason.  Please don't be mindlessly mechanical, but there's no reason to keep typing the same message over and over again by hand either.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe at least as soon as the overall rating is negative, there could be an 'info' icon with that as the hover text.

I know that's already the hover of the downvote button, but people apparently don't get that (I didn't know until today) and this request is about making this detail obvious.